# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843) - Mac OS app

Tags: swift

I get this error when I am trying to connect my Swift Mac OS app to a page running on a sever on my localhost. I have made sure the server is up and running.
This is my info.plist file:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
    </array>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Location Service always in use</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string></string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseDescrciption</key>
    <string>Location Needed</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>$(MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>17.83.148.252</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2017 Meghalee. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And this is the part of the code that tries to access the page. It is from the swift app. There is no error when I build my project. I can't use NSURL as this version of Swift does not have NSUrl it got changed to URLSession, URLRequest and so on:

```
 private func sendtoPHP(nSt : NetworkStatistics,lat : Double, long : Double )
    {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://17.83.148.252/test.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

//        let postString = "a=\(nSt.getCurrentSsid()!)&b=\(nSt.getRssiValue()!)&c=\(nSt.getNoiseMeasurement()!)&d=\(nSt.getWlanChannel()!)&e=\(nSt.getBssid()!)&f=\(nSt.getCountryCode()!)&g=\(nSt.getHardwareAddress()!)&h=\(nSt.getTransmitPower()!)&i=\(lat)&j=\(long)"

        let postString = "a=\(nSt.getCurrentSsid()!)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

I have tried replacing 17.83.148.252 with localhost but it does not work.
Here is the detailed error description:

```
2017-03-08 11:53:40.453196 NetworkHealth_Mac[56146:753522] Unfiltered exception: SSLHostname
2017-03-08 11:53:40.479160 NetworkHealth_Mac[56146:753489] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “17.83.148.252” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey= NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “17.83.148.252” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://17.83.148.252/test.php, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://17.83.148.252/test.php, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I already tried that.Please look at my info.plist, the key NSAppTransportSecurity is there.I found the solution to this. The problem was, I was using a Mac OS server to run the PHP file in the server. Interestingly when I was running localhost/test.php it was working from the browser but not from my swift program (which is on the same machine) .I used this link in my code : https://username-macbook-air.local/test.php instead of https://localhost/test.php. Seems like, when I use localhost , the access is blocked saying "the server does not have a certificate" , even if I include :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

So I figured that Swift 3 in OS X needs a secure connection with an SSL certificate, which is there by default but we just have to find the correct link.